# Spring jdbc call Function

Tags: java, spring, oracle, function, jdbc

I am trying to call a stored function using the SimpleJdbcCall class. The input parameter is a table type, which can have several types. I can’t do it at all, I get an error that the input parameters are incorrect or a handle error. I beg you to help in solving this problem, I enclose a sample code

```
public OutReport callFunction(ReportBuilder request) throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
    SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withFunctionName(functionName)
            .declareParameters(
                    new SqlOutParameter("t_lost_income_rep", OracleTypes.STRUCT, "T_LOST_INCOME_REP"),
                    new SqlParameter("p_Date_Report_Calculate", OracleTypes.DATE),
                    new SqlParameter("p_Reimburse_Agreement_Number", OracleTypes.VARCHAR),
                    new SqlParameter("p_Report_Type", OracleTypes.NUMBER),
                    new SqlParameter("p_address_tab", OracleTypes.STRUCT, "T_LOST_INC_REP_ADDR"));

SqlParameterSource input = new MapSqlParameterSource()
        .addValue("p_Date_Report_Calculate", request.getDateReport())
        .addValue("p_Reimburse_Agreement_Number", request.getAgreementNumber())
        .addValue("p_Report_Type", request.getReportType())
        .addValue("p_address_tab", request.getAddressTabType());
Struct struct = simpleJdbcCall.executeFunction(Struct.class, input);
Object[] resultFunc = struct.getAttributes();
return createReport(resultFunc);
```

and an example of mapping of a java class with an Oracle type

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AddressTabType implements SQLData {

    AddressType addressType;

    @Override
    public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {
        return "t_lost_inc_rep_addr_tab".toUpperCase();
    }

    @Override
    public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName) throws SQLException {
        this.addressType = (AddressType)stream.readObject();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {
        stream.writeObject(getAddressType());
    }
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class AddressType implements SQLData {

    private BigDecimal serivceId;
    private BigDecimal unom;
    private String fiasId;
    private String appartment;

    @Override
    public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {
        return "t_lost_inc_rep_addr".toUpperCase();
    }

    @Override
    public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName) throws SQLException {
        this.serivceId = stream.readBigDecimal();
        this.unom = stream.readBigDecimal();
        this.fiasId = stream.readString();
        this.appartment = stream.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {
        stream.writeBigDecimal(getSerivceId());
        stream.writeBigDecimal(getUnom());
        stream.writeString(getFiasId());
        stream.writeString(getAppartment());
    }
}
```

I really hope for your support. I've been tormented for a long time

Comment: Do you have control over the stored procedure return value? If so you can  simply return a cursor?

Comment: the problem is that I cannot put the p_adress_tab parameter.  in the database it represents a table of another type